# Is there any other decision made by a United Nation General Assembly body that cannot be vetoed by the United Nation Security Council?

Tags: international, united-nations

> The replacement of the Maduro delegation could occur in two ways.
> First, the group could present the credentials challenge to the
> nine-member UN Credentials Committee, which currently includes Antigua
> and Barbuda, Chile, China, Finland, Ghana, Palau, the Russian
> Federation, Sierra Leone, and the United States. **If a majority of the
> Credentials Committee voted to revoke the credentials of Maduro’s
> delegation and to replace them with those of Guaidó’s delegation, then
> the case would be brought before the General Assembly. A simple
> majority vote would be required there to affirm the Credential
> Committee’s recommendation. Neither vote is subject to a veto by the
> five permanent members of the UN Security Council.** This approach would
> be following the usual order for the consideration of credentials.

https://www.perseus-strategies.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Legal-Opinion-UN-Credentials-Challenge-on-Venezuela-2.1.19-FINAL.pdf

The United Nations Credentials Committee is a committee of the United Nations General Assembly, and yet according to the above, it says that the decision made by that committee cannot be vetoed at all by the United Nation Security Council, so I was wondering if there's any body of the United Nations General Assembly that can render decisions that cannot be vetoed by the UNSC. I must clarify that the IMF is a UN body, but not a UNGA body.

Comment: What is the delegation for? How did the dispute arise? There isn't enough context or detail in the question for a reader not familiar with the situation in this moment to know what is going on. There are surely lots of procedural U.N. General Assembly matters about which the U.N. Security Council has no say. The UNSC would generally have no say in UNGA parliamentary procedure and operations, for example. If the UNGA wants to take a lunch break, the UNSC can't say no to that. But it isn't clear what you are getting at or why you think this is a problem or issue.

Comment: Remember that the UNGA represents "everyone" while the UNSC represents "people with nukes who you'd better not piss off". If the UNSC could not veto a decision, they could just nuke the country instead. The purpose of the UN is that people will yell at each other in the UN building *instead of* taking military actions with massive loss of life. So I do not expect the UN to have any process by which someone with immense military power could not formally veto a decision, preventing their need to invoke their military power.